# How to for Jekyll site create "default" page or redirect for the folder?

Tags: jekyll

I'm migrating my site to Jekyll. I put articles to .md files and set `permalink` for all of them. Historically all articles have `/notebook/article_name' URL. It works:

https://fervent-dijkstra-11077c.netlify.com/notebook/2000-01-02-one-two-three

But the `/notebook/` itself has no index page.
https://fervent-dijkstra-11077c.netlify.com/notebook/

I'd like to put there redirect to the root page with list of articles. How to do it?

Sources are here: https://github.com/tseglevskiy/jekyll-test

Comment: Try https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from

Comment: @DavidJacquel sure, but what file to create for it?